# Realtime streaming Kinect Colorstream with MS Expression Encoder 4

Tags: stream, kinect, kinect-sdk, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

i really need some help with the following issue, and i hope you may help me to find a solution.

Iam trying to use MS Kinect and MS Exspression Studio (in C#) for realtime videostreaming, the thing is Kinect only returns a ColorFrame which is provided in several Images (Bitmaps) per second.

Is there a way to livestream this ColorStream within MS Expression Encoder 4? I only figured out how iam able to stream a existing movie or image file.

How iam able to livestream a bunch of ImageFiles, which are provided by the Kinect ColorStream?

I hope someone of you may help me!